# skip method in Class BufferedInputStream is not skipping exactly n bytes

Tags: java, skip, bufferedinputstream

```
        int a  = bis.available();
        System.out.println("*****"+a);
        bis.skip(10000);
        a  = bis.available();
        System.out.println("*****"+a);
        bis.skip(10000);
        a  = bis.available();
        System.out.println("*****"+a);
```

---

Output:

```
*****369608
*****361424
*****351424
```

When I use skip, if I try to skip 10000, it will only skip 8184 bytes. If I do that again, it will work properly this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as specified. From the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)):

> The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0. [...] The actual number of bytes skipped is returned.

Comment: So I need to use this return value to calculate the new value I need to skip again, is that correct? Why this happened..

Comment: Correct. As to why it behaves like that: I don't know, and the spec is vague about it ("variety of reasons"). If I have to guess, I'd say probably some kind of performance optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Your test doesn't prove anything, because you are misusing `available()`. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc *against* using it as the number of bytes remanining in the stream. That's not what it's for.